# How to toggle text of button on click in flutter?

Tags: flutter

after get data from API output is:[L,P is attendance_flag.if click on L it toggle to P and if i click on P it will toggle to A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUltH.png)

but i want this :[it toggle attendance_flag but after some time it will look like first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJxqT.png)

how to change L to P or P to A on click 
this is my code:

```
child: RaisedButton(
      //color: pressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        color: (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'P')
            ? Colors.green
            : (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'A')
            ? Colors.redAccent
            : (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'L')
            ? Colors.orange
            : Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _buttonEnabled = !_buttonEnabled;
            _id = index;
            if (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'P') {
              setState(() {
                _buttonEnabled = false;
                snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] = 'A';
              });
            } else if (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'A') {
              _buttonEnabled = true;
              snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] = 'P';
            }
            else if (snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] == 'L') {
              _buttonEnabled = false;
              _asyncInputDialog(context);
              snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag'] = 'L';
            }
          });

          print("You clicked item number $_id");
        },
        child: Text(_buttonEnabled == true
            ? snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag']
            : _buttonEnabled == false ? snapshot
            .data[index]['attendance_flag'] : 'P')
    ),
```

Comment: give widget code so it will be easy to reply

Comment: (Not an answer, just a suggestion) To simplify your code, instead of changing data in Instance of AsyncSnapshot you should have a variable like String buttonText. Once you do this it will be clear to you that what part of code is causing problem.

Comment: You cannot change the snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag']='L'; it will be just changes at flutter end and when widget rebuilds will again show as per data that was originally there. I think you gettting this data from rest API

Comment: yes data is getting from API

Comment: @Dev can you write code please...because im getting confuzed

Comment: child: Text(_buttonEnabled 
                                                             ? snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag']
                                                             : snapshot.data[index]['attendance_flag']
                                                         )  how to write condition in Text

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by declaring the button in a stateful widget & initially you have to declare a String variable storing "L" in the state class. Then, inside the state class, implement button's method onPressed. Inside onPressed, implement setState method and inside it, change the String variable to "P", which was initially "L".
You can write if else clauses inside the setState method to change the text to your suitable form like in your case you want to change "L" to "P", & "P" to "A".

It would be something like this:

```
class YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  String buttonText = "L";
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
        child: Text(buttonText),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (buttonText == "L") {
              buttonText = "P";
            } else if (buttonText == "P") {
              buttonText = "A";
            }
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Else you can also use ChangeNotifier for the String buttonText & change the button text from anywhere in your app.

Comment: what is abc? can i write buttonText instead of abc

Comment: i tried this but all buttons text become L .if click on L it not change to P

Comment: Did you use my code? I saw your code above. The if else statements you wrote will not change the text from L to P.

Comment: actually it is not toggle the text.but using my code its toggle the text but it does not maintain text

Comment: Ohh! May be, I got your problem. Are you using a ListView.builder to show the buttons in a list? and the button text changes back to L after scrolling? In that case, add a property to ListView.builder => addAutomaticKeepAlives: true

Comment: i have declare 3 variables

Comment: child: Text(_buttonEnabled
                  ? buttontext1
                   :_buttonEnabled
                   ?buttontext2
                    :buttontext3
                    )      buttontext1="P";  buttontext2="L";  buttontext3="L"